# Use of Grep command in Linux

Tags: grep

I want to grep a particular string from a text file at some location and want to display a specific message for that. I do not want to display the grep strings , i want to display my own message for that.
can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of `grep X` in your question? Provide some input/output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if grep -q expression file; then echo FOUND IT; fi
```